# Is there a .any() equivalent in PySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering if there is a way to use `.any()` in Pyspark?

I have the following code in Python, that essentially searches through a specific column of interest in a subset dataframe, and if any of those columns contain `"AD"`, we do not want to process them.

Here is the code in Python:

```
index_list = [
    df.query("id == @id").index 
    for trial in unique_trial_id_list 
    if ~(df.query("id == @trial")["unit"].str.upper().str.contains("AD").any()]
```

Here is a sample dataframe in Pandas.

`ID=1` has the string `'AD'` associated with it, so we want to exclude it from processing. However, `ID=2` does not have that string `'AD'` associated with it and thus we want to include it in further processing.

```
data = [
    [1, "AD"],
    [1, "BC"],
    [1, "DE"],
    [1, "FG"],
    [2, "XY"],
    [2, "BC"],
    [2, "DE"],
    [2, "FG"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "Code"])
df
```

The rub is I do not know how to do this equivalent function in PySpark. I have been able to do a list comprehension for subsetting, and have been able to subset using `contains('AD')` but am stuck when it comes to the `any` part of things.

PySpark Code I've come up with:

```
id = id_list[0] 
test = sdf.select(["ID", "Codes"]).filter(spark_fns.col("ID") == id).filter(~spark_fns.col("Codes").str.contains("AD"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Window function (the max of a boolean is true if there is at least one true value):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "to_exclude",
    ~F.max(F.when(F.col("Code") == "AD", True).otherwise(False)).over(Window.partitionBy("ID"))
).filter(
    F.col("to_exclude")
).drop("to_exclude")

df1.show()
# +---+----+
# | ID|Code|
# +---+----+
# |  2|  XY|
# |  2|  BC|
# |  2|  DE|
# |  2|  FG|
# +---+----+
```

---

Or groupby `id` and using `max` function along with `when` expression to filter the id that contains `AD` in `Code` column, then join with original df :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

filter_df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.max(F.when(F.col("Code") == "AD", True).otherwise(False)).alias("to_exclude")
).filter(F.col("to_exclude"))

df1 = df.join(filter_df, ["id"], "left_anti")
```

---

In Spark 3+, there is also a function `any`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

filter_df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.expr("any(Code = 'AD')").alias("to_exclude")
).filter(F.col("to_exclude"))

df1 = df.join(filter_df, ["id"], "left_anti")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this - 1) find all ID values where Code column contains AD, 2) Filter out rows with such IDs by left anti join

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "Code"])
df_psp = spark.createDataFrame(df)

cols = ["ID"]
df_filter = df_psp.filter(F.col("Code").like('%AD%')).select(cols).distinct()
df_out = df_psp.join(df_filter, cols, "left_anti")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema='Id int')
any = df.limit(1).count() > 0
```